# XCode - Multiple targets, Multiple *internationalized* names?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, internationalization

I've got an internationalized iPhone project. In the various `${lang}.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` files I've got a single key, `CFBundleName = "My App Name"`.

That's working fine for a single target, but I can't make it work for multiple targets.

I'd like to have several translated `InfoPlistMyApp.strings` files for the main target, plus several `InfoPlistMyAppLite.strings` files for the lite version.  But I can't figure out how to set it up. The `InfoPlist.strings` name seems to be set in stone, so I can't replace it dynamically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Turns out this is quite easy, if laborious. You can have several InfoPlist.strings, one-enabled-per-target, and they can each be internationalized, *as long as each set is in a different Xcode group*.

Set up a directory structure like this:

```
.../AppName/
            en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings  <-- Contains CFBundleDisplayName
            it.lproj/InfoPlist.strings  <-- ...
            ...
.../AppNameLite/
            en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings  <-- ...
            it.lproj/InfoPlist.strings  <-- ...
            ...
```

Import those files into Xcode groups, so it looks like this:

[image]

Right-click "Groups & Files" (top left of Xcode) and make sure "Target Membership" is visible, then go through your targets, checking the the right set of strings is enabled for each.