# Multiple target with different display name for different language

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XCode - Multiple targets, Multiple *internationalized* names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807377/xcode-multiple-targets-multiple-internationalized-names)

When you create a new project with Xcode 4.2+, there is an `InfoPlist.strings`, you can specific different app display name for different language. For example:

```
InfoPlist.strings (English) - "CFBundleDisplayName" = "English Name";
InfoPlist.strings (Chinese) - "CFBundleDisplayName" = "中文";
```

This works fine for **single target**. How to display different display name for multiple target?

Comment: see this similar approach
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2704376/482899